# Add links to chrome apps tab

Tags: google-chrome

(not sure which StackExchange community to use for this question)

I would like to add some web links to the `chrome://apps/` tab. Is this possible?

Currently I have this:

[image]

Which I can reorganize a bit, but I do not know how to add my own links to this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just drag the link to the app page 
[See here](https://www.labnol.org/software/websites-as-chrome-apps/20520/)